# Encoding issue with one of the letter of Azerbaijani alphabet

Tags: python, pysimplegui

The following is the code which fills in the docx file with a required data, automates the process. If you noticed its interface is in Azerbaijani and the problem is that I can not make with one of the letters (namely: "Ə") of the Azerbaijani language to receive as it is in input field of PySimpleGUI. All letters are received and displayed except this one - "Ə". This letter is so widespread that I can not do without it.
Any suggestions ? It has to do something with unicode, but at what extent I could not figure out yet.

```
from pathlib import Path
import PySimpleGUI as sg
from docxtpl import DocxTemplate


def main():
    document_path = Path(__file__).parent / "AFC_T.docx"
    doc = DocxTemplate(document_path)

    
    layout = [
        [sg.Text("Müqavilənin nömrəsi:"), sg.Input(key="NUMBER", do_not_clear=False)],
        [sg.Text("Müqavilənin tarixi:"), sg.Input(key="DATE", do_not_clear=False)],
        [sg.Text("Müştəri:"), sg.Input(key="CUSTOMER", do_not_clear=False)],
        [sg.Text("Direktor, A.S.A.:"), sg.Input(key="DIRNAMESURNAMEPA", do_not_clear=False)],
        [sg.Text("Bitmə tarixi:"), sg.Input(key="EXPIRY", do_not_clear=False)],
        [sg.Text("Ünvan:"), sg.Input(key="ADDRESS", do_not_clear=False)],
        [sg.Text("VÖEN:"), sg.Input(key="TAXID", do_not_clear=False)],
        [sg.Text("Bank:"), sg.Input(key="BANK", do_not_clear=False)],
        [sg.Text("H/h:"), sg.Input(key="BANKACCOUNT", do_not_clear=False)],
        [sg.Text("Filialın kodu:"), sg.Input(key="BRANCHCODE", do_not_clear=False)],
        [sg.Text("Bankın VÖEN-i:"), sg.Input(key="BANKTAXID", do_not_clear=False)],
        [sg.Text("M/h:"), sg.Input(key="CORRESACC", do_not_clear=False)],
        [sg.Text("SWIFT:"), sg.Input(key="SWIFT", do_not_clear=False)],
        [sg.Button("Müqavilə yarat"), sg.Button("Çıxış")],
    ]

    window = sg.Window("Müqavilə Generatoru", layout, font='Any 15', element_justification="right", auto_size_text=True)

    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == "Çıxış":
            break
        if event == "Müqavilə yarat":
            
            doc.render(values)
            output_path = Path(__file__).parent / f"{values['CUSTOMER']}-müqavilə.docx"
            doc.save(output_path)
            sg.popup("Fayl yaddaşa verildi", f"Fayl burada saxlabıldı: {output_path}")

    window.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you for providing a reproducible example.  It displays fine on my system so it is likely an environment issue with your default font not supporting that glyph.  I am using Windows 10 64-bit.  You?

Comment: Try choosing a specific font instead of "ANY".  I'm assuming that if you manually set a string containing the character and send it to the document, the character is displayed in the document.

Comment: Mark Tolonen: I use the very same system Win 10 64 bit and more is that I have tried it one 2 different machines with the same success.

Comment: WombatPM: I did, it did not solve the issue.